# How to get each group

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get each group starting with "BO_" using python regex.
(The data was from: https://github.com/commaai/opendbc)

Original Text:

```
...
BS_:

BU_: XXX CAMERA FRONT_RADAR ADRV APRK


BO_ 53 ACCELERATOR: 32 XXX
 SG_ CHECKSUM : 0|16@1+ (1,0) [0|65535] "" XXX
 SG_ COUNTER : 16|8@1+ (1,0) [0|255] "" XXX
 SG_ GEAR : 192|3@1+ (1,0) [0|7] "" XXX
 SG_ ACCELERATOR_PEDAL : 40|8@1+ (1,0) [0|255] "" XXX

BO_ 64 GEAR_ALT: 32 XXX
 SG_ CHECKSUM : 0|16@1+ (1,0) [0|65535] "" XXX
 SG_ COUNTER : 16|8@1+ (1,0) [0|255] "" XXX
 SG_ GEAR : 32|3@1+ (1,0) [0|7] "" XXX

BO_ 69 GEAR: 24 XXX
 SG_ CHECKSUM : 0|16@1+ (1,0) [0|65535] "" XXX
 SG_ COUNTER : 16|8@1+ (1,0) [0|255] "" XXX
 SG_ GEAR : 44|3@1+ (1,0) [0|7] "" XXX

...
CM_ SG_ 96 BRAKE_PRESSURE "User applied brake pedal pressure. Ramps from computer applied pressure on falling edge of cruise. Cruise cancels if !=0";
CM_ SG_ 101 BRAKE_POSITION "User applied brake pedal position, max is ~700. Signed on some vehicles";
CM_ SG_ 373 PROBABLY_EQUIP "aeb equip?";
```

I want to capture BO_ blocks whose BO id(`BO_ ID`) is in [53, 69] like this:

```
BO_ 53 ACCELERATOR: 32 XXX
 SG_ CHECKSUM : 0|16@1+ (1,0) [0|65535] "" XXX
 SG_ COUNTER : 16|8@1+ (1,0) [0|255] "" XXX
 SG_ GEAR : 192|3@1+ (1,0) [0|7] "" XXX
 SG_ ACCELERATOR_PEDAL : 40|8@1+ (1,0) [0|255] "" XXX

BO_ 69 GEAR: 24 XXX
 SG_ CHECKSUM : 0|16@1+ (1,0) [0|65535] "" XXX
 SG_ COUNTER : 16|8@1+ (1,0) [0|255] "" XXX
 SG_ GEAR : 44|3@1+ (1,0) [0|7] "" XXX
```

What I've tried so far was
1)capturing BO_ and relevant SGs using the regex below but it only captured each BO and the first SG groups.

```
BO_ (\w+) (\w+) *: (\w+) (\w+)\n (SG_ (\w+) : (\d+)\|(\d+)@(\d+)([\+|\-]) \(([0-9.+\-eE]+),([0-9.+\-eE]+)\) \[([0-9.+\-eE]+)\|([0-9.+\-eE]+)\] \"(.*)\" (.*)\n)*
```

2. using greedy method but it captured all BOs at once except the last occurence.

```
BO_ (\w+) (\w+) *: (\w+) (\w+)((.|\n)*)BO_
```

Also, for selecting only BOs including digits in the list [53, 69], I used raw f-string method something like `rf"{digit}"` in regex expressions.

Comment: Welcome! Please read [ask] and write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title. For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily capture paragraphs with [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) using the [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) (`inline s`) and [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) (`inline m`) flags.

Regex (with inline flags): `(?sm)BO_ (?:53|69) .+?^$`

Usage (pick one):

```py
re.findall(r"(?sm)BO_ (?:53|69) .+?^$", text)
```

```py
re.findall(r"BO_ (?:53|69) .+?^$", text, flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

This lazily captures all lines from `BO_ 53`  or `BO_ 69`  to a blank line `^$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/kwXccM/2)).

Comment: It looks amazing. By the way which `re` method can I use in this case? I've tried to apply your suggestion to my codes like `BO_regex = re.compile(r"(?s)\BO_ (?:53|69) .+?^$", re.DOTALL)`, `matching_BO = BO_regex.match(original_text)`, `print(matching_BO)` but it gave me None. (I also tried with `search`, `findall` methods and so on.)

Comment: I had forgotten regex101 automatically applies re.MULTILINE, see my edit.

Comment: Also, with the inline flags `(?sm)`, you do not need to specify them in the call arguments.

Comment: @Stella `re.findall(r"^BO_ (?:53|69) .+?^$", text, re.S | re.M)`

Answer (score 1):

Inside of jumping through hoops in order to parse a `dbc` file with regular expressions, I suggest you use a proper parser like [cantools](https://github.com/cantools/cantools):

> CAN BUS tools in Python 3.
>
> - `DBC`*, `KCD`*, SYM, ARXML 3&4 and CDD file parsing.
> - CAN message encoding and decoding.
> - Simple and extended signal multiplexing.
> - Diagnostic DID encoding and decoding.
> - `candump` output decoder.
> - Node `tester`_.
> - `C` source code generator.
> - CAN bus monitor.
> - Graphical plots of signals.